# Model theory of valued

Tags: field-theory, model-theory

I am currently reading these [notes](http://www.logique.jussieu.fr/~zoe/papiers/CUP-MT.pdf) on model theory of valued fields, in the section 3.3 appears this theorem:

> **Theorem.** Let $K$ and $L$ be valued fields, with residue fields $k_K$ and $k_L$
>   respectively, and value groups $\Gamma_K$, $\Gamma_L$ respectively. Assume they satisfy
>   one of the following set of conditions:
>
> (a) The residue fields of $K$ and $L$ are of characteristic  $0$.
>
> (b) $K$ and $L$ are of characteristic $0$, the residue fields are of characteristic $p > 0$, the value groups have a smallest positive element, and
>   in both fields the value of $p$ is a fininite multiple $e$ of this smallest
>   positive element.
>
> Then: $(1)$. $$K\equiv L \Longleftrightarrow k_K\equiv k_L  \ and \ \Gamma_K \equiv \Gamma_L $$
>
> (2) If $K$ is a valued subfield of $L$, then
>   $$ K\prec L \Longleftrightarrow  k_K\prec k_L  \ and \ \Gamma_K \prec\Gamma_L$$

this is known as the AKE-principle, but I have not been able to deduce a demonstration of this (in the notes be omitted), any hint  is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The proof of the AKE-principle (this stands for Ax-Kochen-Ershov, by the way) is quite involved. You can find a complete proof in [these notes](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~vddries/valfields.dvi) by Lou van den Dries (Theorems 5.1 and 6.13).

By the way, Chatzidakis seems to have omitted the hypothesis that $K$ and $L$ are Henselian in her statement of the theorem that you've quoted. She points out in the previous paragraph that it's necessary though!